# How much does 1 tick of damage increase the bonus chance to get a critical hit?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Since there is normally (on stock) a 2% chance to critical hit. How does one determine how much 1 tick of damage adds to the 10% bonus chance [to get a critical hit]?Since there is normally (on stock) a 2% chance to critical hit. How does one determine how much 1 tick of damage adds to the 10% bonus chance [to get a critical hit]?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late but if you're still wondering, here is what your looking for:

Based upon the wiki's explanation, it would be reasonable to assume that the relationship between damage and bonus crit chance is linear up until 800 damage points is reached.

So, to answer you question, one tick of damage is 1/800 of the damage needed to reach the maximum 10%

1 / 800 = 0.00125

0.1 * 0.00125 = 0.000125 = **0.0125%**

Therefore, for every tick of damage you do, it will add 0.0125% to your base crit chance of 2%

Also note that this value is for **non-melee** sources of damage

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Critical_hits